# Putty paste text until newline char or don't paste newline char

Tags: terminal, shell, putty

I would like to prevent accident paste & execute scenarios in PuTTY.

I see this ideally by preventing PuTTY to *do* what it had pasted - somehow to omit the newline char or to paste text up to first newline char - both of these two would be acceptable.

Is that possible?

Comment: What about a third option: Disable *paste by right Click*, instead show classic right click menu

Comment: Hi. It doesn't help  -  then I would still be able to paste newline and have pasted text immediately executed...

Comment: Someone has answered it here. https://serverfault.com/a/731023/414514. Disabling right click is only to prevent accidental paste

Comment: Take a look at the "bracketed paste mode" feature supported by most terminal emulators (including PuTTY since version 0.63) and several apps (including readline 7.0 / bash 4.4).